# Prove that $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod {p^{k}} $ is solvable iff $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod {p}$ is solvable

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod {p^{k}} $ is solvable iff  $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod {p}$. In the case of solvability, prove that  $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod {p^{k}} $ has exactly two incongruent solutions modulo $p^k$

If we assume that  $x^{2} \equiv a \pmod {p}$ is solvable, then $p|x^{2}-a$. We want to show that $p^{k}|x^{2}-a$. But how can we know that $p^k$ divides $x^{2}-a$? How do we know that $p^k$ isn't greater than $x^{2}-a$ for example?

Kinda feel like my thinking is all over the place. And how can I show that there are only two solutions? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't know for sure that $p^k$ divides $x^2-a$. But you want to find some $x' \equiv x \pmod p$ such that $p^k$ divides $(x')^2 - a$.

Comment: When $x_0^2\equiv x_1^2\pmod {p^k}$, then $x_0\equiv x_1$ or $x_0\equiv-x_1$ hence there are only two solutions.

Comment: @Mastrem  Well, you need to argue that a bit.  After all, the equation $x^2\equiv 0^2\pmod 9$ has three solutions ($0,3,6$).

Comment: @lulu I can't edit my comment anymore, but yes, you are right. I should've put $p$ instead of $p^k$. This can be based of theorem $58$ in Hardy and Wright

Comment: See [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime, that $a$ is not divisible by $p$ and that $x_r^2 = a + kp^r$ for some integer k and positive integer $r$.  Let $m$ be an inverse of
$2x_r$ mod $p$. Then

$$
(x_r - km p^r)^2 = x_r^2 - 2km x_r p^r + k^2 m^2 p^{2r}
$$

If we put  $x_{r+1} =x_r - km p^r$ then

$$
x_{r+1}^2 \equiv a \mod p^{r+1}
$$

A different argument will be needed if $p=2$ or if $p$ divides $a$.